# Replace memcpy with memcpy_s with an unsigned char

Tags: c++, pointers, memcpy

Let's suppose we have a legacy code that performs this operation:

```
unsigned char* dest = new unsigned char[length];
memcpy(dest, source, length);
```

where the pointer `source` is passed as input parameter of that method. `length` is an unsigned long variable.

Now I want to replace the memcpy call, considered not secure, with the secure version of it, so with ***memcpy_s***.
In base of its documentation, this method takes three parameters,

1. destination
2. Size of the destination buffer, in bytes for memcpy_s and wide characters (wchar_t) for wmemcpy_s.
3. the source
4. the number of characters to copy.

I'have some concern regarding the fourth parameter. Shall it be something like that:

```
err = memcpy_s(dest, sizeof(dest), a2, length * sizeof (unsigned char));
```

Is that correct? Thanks

Comment: "Considered not secure" mostly by Microsoft. If you *know* the size to be sufficient, there is nothing wrong with plain `memcpy()`.

Comment: `sizeof(dest)` is clearly wrong as it is the size of the pointer and not of the allocated memory... If you are using C++, you should consider using `std::string` or `std::vector` among other and avoid manual memory managment and manual copy...

Comment: I'm firmly with @DevSolar. `#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE`, I think it is, and shut the compiler up.

Comment: Also memcpy_s is broken. The specs say: "except that the following errors are detected at runtime and cause the entire destination range [dest, dest+destsz) to be zeroed out" with one of the errors being: "the source and the destination objects overlap". So on overlap you get an error, good, but also your source is partially zerored out, bad. There is no way to recover from that error. On the other hand `memcpy()` will in practice just work with overlaps if `dst < src` , which is half the cases for the error.

Comment: May I ask why you haven't considered `std::vector<unsigned char> dest(source, source + length);` as *"the secure version of it"*?

Comment: @Phil1970 Thanks. May I ask so the correct value to pass as destination size? Something like length * sizeof (dest)?

Comment: @Bob__ tbh, I was tasked to do so and replace the calls with the new _s version

Comment: Assuming that the original code is correct (we don't know what the source is), then you would use `memset_s(dest, length, source, length)` but we cannot know source length from the code shown.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`memcpy_s()` is not fundamentally "more secure". It just performs a [few sanity checks](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy). In your case, some of these are even redundant. So, if you want to "defend" your function implementation from invalid arguments, you could make sure `source` is not `nullptr`; all the other "security" checks are guaranteed to pass anyway:

- The amount copied is the same as the destination size, no larger.
- The destination is not `nullptr` - you just successfully allocated it.
- If you were able to allocate `length`, then it can't be more than `RSIZE_MAX`.

That's it, no need to use `memcpy_s()`.

Also, `sizeof(unsigned char)` is 1, [necessarily](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/types).